# dump all USB device properties into file

Tags: windows, usb, device-manager, properties

I am looking for a way to dump all the USB devices' properties (e.g. Device description, Friendly name, Driver key, ...etc.) that are usually found under details in device manager, Windows.

any approach using code or ready-to-use app would be helpful.

PS: I tried USBlayzer, USBtree, and Powershell code (Get-PnpDevice)
they all didn't help as they are limited in properties and couldn't dump every single one.

Answer (score 1):

The majority of USB-device related info is stored in registry:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB

Comment: I've checked it already before posting... and I couldn't find all the properties, I found only 11 out of 70 enlisted properties in Device Manager!